# How can I show loader in react-native until the response is fetched

Tags: react-native

In my react-native application, I am populating the data in `componentDidMount`. However there is some delay until I get the data so I want to show the loader until then. To do that, I am using Activity Indicator.

My code-

```
    import {
      Switch,
      ScrollView,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      Image,
      View,
      TouchableOpacity,
      ActivityIndicator
    } from 'react-native';

        class AccordionView extends Component {
          state = {
            activeSections: [],
            newData: []
          };


             _renderContent = section => {
                return (
                  <View style={styles.content}>
                    <Text>{section.content}</Text>
                  </View>
                );
              };
        }

   render() {
       if (!this.state.newData) {
          return (
            <ActivityIndicator
              animating={true}
              style={styles.indicator}
              size="large"
            />
          );
        }
else if (this.state.newData.length === 0){
   return <Text>No records found!!</Text> 
}
else{
    return (
              <Accordion
                sections={this.state.newData}
                activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
                renderSectionTitle={this._renderSectionTitle}
                renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
                renderContent={this._renderContent}
                onChange={this._updateSections}
              />
            );
          }
        }
}
```

CSS-

```
indicator: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 80
      }
```

My `newData` has the updated response after the api call hence I am doing something like above but I do not see any Indicator/Loader on my page load until the data is fetched. Can someone let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: use newData.length > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newData is an empty array and `![]` evaluates to false. Make your newData in state to initially have some falsy value like `null` or `undefined`

Comment: that will also help you distinguish between a state where data hasn't been loaded yet to a state where data has been loaded but is empty (sometimes you would want to render a special empty state for that case)

Comment: The loader even shows up when the length is 0.What I want is to show the data as "No data found yet" if the response return 200 with 0 length. How can we handle this as well?

Comment: When you get empty response, initialize the data in state to an empty array and then in render function add an `else if` checking for the condition `this.state.data.length === 0`. And finally after this `else if`, put the code that you wanna show when u have some data

Comment: I can do that. My concern is to show the loader until the data is fetched. So if the response returns an array with values, it should render the accordions else display the message "No records found."

Comment: The loader will be shown till the data in state has some falsy value. Once you make a request to the api, you populate the data with either an empty array or array of records. If the array is empty, show no records found, else show accordion. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: This is what I wrote in the comment, update your render function, and follow the steps I wrote above to achieve this

Comment: Please see my Question updated above. I am doing something like this.

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem with this? No loader being shown? And you have a missing closing brace for else if

Comment: Also if the loader is not being shown, the reason is still what I gave as the asnwer